# Unwanted behaviour when CSS scaling responsive images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-transitions

Reproduced problem in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pj9gjc8d/

```
HTML:
 <div class="box zoomable-box">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
 </div>

 <div class="box zoomable-box">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
 </div>

 <div class="box zoomable-box">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
 </div>

SCSS:
.box {
  width: 33.3333333333333%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;

  img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  }

  &:hover {
    img {
      transform: scale(1.3);
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, what I need is remove unwanted behaviour with CSS scaling. Problem can be seen when hovering middle image at its right side in Google Chrome. Div seems to be scaled wrongly to its original proportions.

Thanks for help!

edit: Tried for better description: When I am hovering over the middle image - in the process of scaling - there is some kind of wrong resize - for a moment div is smaller and there is pixel whitespace next to it to fill free space. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeaU9.jpg

Comment: What exactly is wrong, "Problem can be seen" is not really helpful. I get a white vertical line in Safari, but nothing in Chrome.

Comment: When I am hovering over the middle image - in the process of scaling - there is some kind of wrong resize - for a moment div is smaller and there is pixel whitespace next to it to fill free space. Tried to catch it here http://i.imgur.com/WtkXfiY.jpg

Comment: I get that pixel whitepsace in Safari, but not Chrome. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, 64 bit, I dont get that pixel whitespace at all resolutions but dont really want it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem related with a difference between calculus of a transformed element

Can be seen more easily here

I have removed the scaling, so the image should stay unchanged. But in some cases, it fails. (and is easier to see here)

```css
.box {
  width: 33.3333333333333%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
.box:hover  img {
      transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box zoomable-box">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box zoomable-box">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box zoomable-box">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

And can be solved increasing slightly the coverture of the image inside the div

```css
.box {
  width: 33.3333333333333%;
  width: calc(100% / 3);   /* just as a easier to read alternative */
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100.1%;   /* modified from 100% */
    height: auto;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
  
.box:hover  img {
      transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="box zoomable-box">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box zoomable-box">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box zoomable-box">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/O8xteuL.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

The real solution is setting the width of the image slightly greater than the container. You only need this to be around half a pixel, so it could be even lower than 100.1%.

I have changed also the 33.33% to a more modern expression, but this is just a personal taste.

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm using Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)) on Mac and do not see this issue, I believe your problem lies with webkit's *subpixel* rendering.

You'll see that your division of widths is `33.33333333%` - which in some instances, will result in a tiny fraction of a line.

Again, this is more of a browser issue, so I wouldn't worry too much about it, since this will be something browsers of the future will be able to address.

https://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/

In your specific case, it could be to do with the use of full-width images in these 33% width div's.

I would minimise this problem by making the beige background color as part of the div itself rather than the images inside them.

Comment: Thanks for answer, for the part with "I would minimise this problem by making the beige background color as part of the div itself rather than the images inside them." - That would be superb but those are just example placeholders. Unfortunately I use normal photos where problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when I change the `float` of the box to `right` it is fixed for me.

Moreover, you could use a width of `calc(100% / 3)` instead of `33.3333333…%`.

Comment: Float: right unfortunately didnt work me.. same problem